# Sending Personal Computer's Screenshot of text to e-reader makes text blurrier than before. Why?

Tags: ebook-readers

Sending Personal Computer's Screenshot of text to e-reader makes text blurrier than before when I embed the screenshot into a word document/pdf file. Why?
Image looks fine on a personal computer.

Would a new e-book reader fix this problem? Is this an artifact of old e-book readers?

Answer (score 1):

Most e-readers are optimized to display monochrome text, with each pixel of a *font* placed by the operating system and software to maximize legibility.

On the other hand, a screenshot captures the pixels *as shown on the display*, which are modified to reduce aliasing and to make letters appear rounded. To do this, the letters are displayed in shade of gray, as shown below.

[image: Screenshot]

If you *must* include a screenshot of text in an e-book, there are a few things that could help.

- Increase contrast and reduce gamma with an image editor such as free [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/).
- Reduce the number of colors to two, i.e., black and white.

The image below shows both effects applied.

[image: Modified Screenshot]

Far better, though, would be to take the screenshot and to convert the image to text using optical character recognition, OCR with a tools such as [FreeOCR](http://www.paperfile.net/), as shown below.

[image: FreeOCR of Screenshot]

With care, this will reproduce the text of the screenshot as *characters*, not as a gray-scale image.